# dyShading R dygraph

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am using the `dygraphs` package and I would like to add multiple shaded regions using the `dyShading` function. I would like not to have to specify manually the shaded region as it is done in the help of the function:

```
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  dyShading(from = "1920-1-1", to = "1930-1-1") %>%
  dyShading(from = "1940-1-1", to = "1950-1-1")
```

But instead, make a loop on the regions. It would look like something like that (that does not work!):

```
data %>% dygraph()  %>%
for( period in ok_periods ) dyShading(from = period$from , to = period$to )
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks you very much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example:

```
#create dygraph
dg <- dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures")

#add shades
for( period in ok_periods ) {
  dg <- dyShading(dg, from = period$from , to = period$to )
}

#show graph
dg
```

If you have periods in a list:

```
ok_periods <- list(
  list(from = "1920-1-1", to = "1930-1-1"),
  list(from = "1940-1-1", to = "1950-1-1"),
  list(from = "1960-1-1", to = "1970-1-1")
)
```

#### Using pipe

If you want to use pipe, you could define a new function

```
add_shades <- function(x, periods, ...) {
  for( period in periods ) {
    x <- dyShading(x, from = period$from , to = period$to, ... )
  }
  x
}
```

and use it in a chain:

```
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  add_shades(ok_periods, color = "#FFFFCC" )
```