# dygraph R package: dyShading() to select by seasons periodically

Tags: r, dygraphs

I have a question about the `dyShading()` function in `dygraph` R package.

I would like to select a certain season periodically instead of "from" time point to "to" time point, I don't know if there is any easy quick way to select them instead of coding them manually year by year.

For example, here is example:

```html
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  dyShading(from = "1920-1-1", to = "1930-1-1") %>%
  dyShading(from = "1940-1-1", to = "1950-1-1")
```

In this example, I would like to `dyShading()` Dec, Jan and Feb in each year.

I am not sure how to do it.

I appreciate any replies!

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyShading R dygraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805017/dyshading-r-dygraph)

Comment: OK. Thank you so much!