# How can I add multiple shades with reactive() within shiny app?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I have tried to add multiple shades in dygrapgh function using for loop. but I couldn't.

Honestly, I was looking for the solution for more than a week, I really can't find any suggestions.

Please help !

I wrote this code:

```
dg= reactive ({
 dygraph(X1(), main ="interactive graph",
                  xlab = "time frame",
                  ylab = "records" ) %>% dyRangeSelector()

           }) 

# I have a table for the shades to be added, it's defined with reactive

shade_tab=reactive({ df[df$Equipement==input$NameOfMachine,] })  

# add shades

for( i in 1:nrow(shade_tab())) 
           { dg()= dyShading(dg(), from= shade_tab()$Date[i],
                  to= shade_tab()$Date[i] + 24*60*60 ,  
                  color = 'black')
           }
output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({ dg() })
```

This is the code I have tried, but I always get the error message.:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext:
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do
something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or
observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
46: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
45: .dependents$register
44: shade_tab
43: nrow
42: server [C:\Users\Curiosity\Desktop\Shiny Interface/server.R#90]
 1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do
something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or 
observer.)
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Thank you !

Comment: You have to do operations on the `reactive` expression inside either another `reactive` or an `observe`

Comment: I have made another reactive but i got errors ! can you correct the code please ?

Comment: You need to provide sample data of your variables you use: `X1()`,`df`, `input$NameOfMachine`

Comment: Ok ! wait for a minute please

Comment: X1() is a xts object 


                                |  G.pk 
---------------------------      | ----------------------
2014-02-10 18:54:13      |      0.7210235
2014-02-10 19:22:11      |      0.7628376                                               2014-02-10 19:24:21      |       0.6971685 
2014-02-11 09:01:32      |       0.4503746 
2014-02-11 09:04:41      |       0.7056433 
2014-02-11 09:22:57      |        0.7525473

Date     | Header
 ------   | ------
Cell       | Cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyShading R dygraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805017/dyshading-r-dygraph)

Comment: I have seen all these questions, but they are not answering mine. The problem is that my grapgh is defined earlier with reactive(). and when I try add shades, I should also use another reactive(). but I am  not sure if that would be possible or correct ?

Comment: You have talked about observe function. any suggestion on how can I use to add shades instead of using reactive() ?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a quick trial within observe() as I find it easier to handle input changes. Change the input value to see 1 or 2 shaded areas.

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(DT)

# ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  numericInput("input", "select", value=1, min=1, max=2),
  dygraphOutput("dyPlot"),
  dataTableOutput("dt")
))

# server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(from = c("1920-1-1", "1940-1-1"), to = c("1930-1-1", "1950-1-1"), range = c(1, 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  observe({
    df_up <- df[df$range <= input$input,]
    dy <- dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% dyRangeSelector()
    for(i in 1:nrow(df_up)) {
      dy <- dy %>% dyShading(from = df_up$from[i], to = df_up$to[i])
    }
    output$dyPlot <- renderDygraph(dy)

    output$dt <- renderDataTable(df_up)
  })
})
```